# Linking error in test program with RTP (Real-Time Transport Protocol)

Tags: c++, linux, compiler-errors, g++, rtp

I am trying to compile a simple test program using rtp (Real-Time Transport Protocol). Unfortunately I get a linking error I can not get rid off. Here is the Code i try to compile with:

```
g++ -v main.cpp -o rtp -lccrtp
```

Here is the main.cpp

```
#include <ccrtp/rtp.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    ost::RTPSession s(ost::InetHostAddress("127.0.0.1"),9000);  // bind reception socket.
     
    return 0;
}
```

and the output:

```
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=g++
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/8/lto-wrapper
OFFLOAD_TARGET_NAMES=nvptx-none
OFFLOAD_TARGET_DEFAULT=1
Target: x86_64-linux-gnu
Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Debian 8.3.0-6' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-8/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,ada,c++,go,brig,d,fortran,objc,obj-c++ --prefix=/usr --with-gcc-major-version-only --program-suffix=-8 --program-prefix=x86_64-linux-gnu- --enable-shared --enable-linker-build-id --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-nls --enable-bootstrap --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --with-default-libstdcxx-abi=new --enable-gnu-unique-object --disable-vtable-verify --enable-libmpx --enable-plugin --enable-default-pie --with-system-zlib --with-target-system-zlib --enable-objc-gc=auto --enable-multiarch --disable-werror --with-arch-32=i686 --with-abi=m64 --with-multilib-list=m32,m64,mx32 --enable-multilib --with-tune=generic --enable-offload-targets=nvptx-none --without-cuda-driver --enable-checking=release --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-linux-gnu --target=x86_64-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
gcc version 8.3.0 (Debian 8.3.0-6) 
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-v' '-o' 'rtp' '-shared-libgcc' '-mtune=generic' '-march=x86-64'
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/8/cc1plus -quiet -v -imultiarch x86_64-linux-gnu -D_GNU_SOURCE main.cpp -quiet -dumpbase main.cpp -mtune=generic -march=x86-64 -auxbase main -version -o /tmp/ccMnYiXi.s
GNU C++14 (Debian 8.3.0-6) version 8.3.0 (x86_64-linux-gnu)
    compiled by GNU C version 8.3.0, GMP version 6.1.2, MPFR version 4.0.2, MPC version 1.1.0, isl version isl-0.20-GMP

GGC heuristics: --param ggc-min-expand=100 --param ggc-min-heapsize=131072
ignoring duplicate directory "/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/8"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/local/include/x86_64-linux-gnu"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/8/../../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/include"
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 /usr/include/c++/8
 /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/8
 /usr/include/c++/8/backward
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/8/include
 /usr/local/include
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/8/include-fixed
 /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu
 /usr/include
End of search list.
GNU C++14 (Debian 8.3.0-6) version 8.3.0 (x86_64-linux-gnu)
    compiled by GNU C version 8.3.0, GMP version 6.1.2, MPFR version 4.0.2, MPC version 1.1.0, isl version isl-0.20-GMP

GGC heuristics: --param ggc-min-expand=100 --param ggc-min-heapsize=131072
Compiler executable checksum: 3c854693d01dc9a844a56a0b1ab1c0f4
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-v' '-o' 'rtp' '-shared-libgcc' '-mtune=generic' '-march=x86-64'
 as -v --64 -o /tmp/ccBl5GBx.o /tmp/ccMnYiXi.s
GNU assembler version 2.31.1 (x86_64-linux-gnu) using BFD version (GNU Binutils for Debian) 2.31.1
COMPILER_PATH=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/8/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/8/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/8/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/
LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/8/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/8/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/8/../../../../lib/:/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/:/lib/../lib/:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/:/usr/lib/../lib/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/8/../../../:/lib/:/usr/lib/
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-v' '-o' 'rtp' '-shared-libgcc' '-mtune=generic' '-march=x86-64'
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/8/collect2 -plugin /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/8/liblto_plugin.so -plugin-opt=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/8/lto-wrapper -plugin-opt=-fresolution=/tmp/cc36T3hM.res -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc_s -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lc -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc_s -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc --build-id --eh-frame-hdr -m elf_x86_64 --hash-style=gnu -dynamic-linker /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 -pie -o rtp /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/8/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/Scrt1.o /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/8/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crti.o /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/8/crtbeginS.o -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/8 -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/8/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/8/../../../../lib -L/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -L/lib/../lib -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -L/usr/lib/../lib -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/8/../../.. /tmp/ccBl5GBx.o -lccrtp -lstdc++ -lm -lgcc_s -lgcc -lc -lgcc_s -lgcc /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/8/crtendS.o /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/8/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crtn.o
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccBl5GBx.o: undefined reference to symbol '_ZNK7ucommon14JoinableThread9is_activeEv'
/usr/bin/ld: //lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libucommon.so.8: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Looks like you also need -lucommon

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the fast reply. That directed me to the solution. I also needed to install

```
libcommoncpp2-dev
```

and now it compiles with:

```
g++ -lccrtp -lucommon -lcommoncpp -o rtp main.cpp
```

without any errors. Thanks again.